# How do I work with complex numbers in Eigen (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen

I am successfully working with Eigen and I'm trying to understand a few details with complex numbers.

1. How do I multiply a Matrix or Vector by a complex constant?  Multiplying to complex matrices is easy; likewise with inner products of complex vectors and matrices.
2. How do I assign a complex value to a matrix element?  I've tried:

This works fine (Visual Studio)

```
kx.real()(0, 0) = 1.0;
```

This throws a compiler error

```
kz_r.imag()(0, ii) =1.0
```

The error I get is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'double' to 'double &'        \eigen\src\core\mathfunctions.h 919

Comment: Why did this get a *-1*?  I thought if question was marked down, you had to leave an explanation...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `std::complex<double>` (or `float`):

```
std::complex<double> c(1,1);
Eigen::MatrixXd R1; R1.setRandom(2,2);
Eigen::MatrixXcd C1 = c*R1; // multiply complex*real
Eigen::MatrixXcd C2 = c*C1; // complex scalar times complex matrix
C1(0,0) = c; // assign complex value.
```

Comment: Thanks... I was having a hard time going through the documentation to find this.  It seems that you *can* assign to the real part of a matrix element, but you *cannot* assign to the imaginary part of a matrix element.

Comment: Could it be that your `kz_r` is a real-valued matrix? In that case `.imag()` would be a non-writable zero-matrix expression.